# When does Rails perform the query and loads into memory?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

If I have a User table and House table and I do this:

```
users = User.where(status: 3)

homes = Home.joins(:user).merge(users)
```

On the first assignation am I performing a query already? Or it waits until the second to perform the query? Or it does it when you actually try to access any of those results? How does Rails manage to know when to perform the query?

Comment: None of your query actually excuted, this is what called `lazy` evaluation. http://rubyinrails.com/2014/01/08/what-is-lazy-loading-in-rails/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` method returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, and by itself this object does not issue a database query. It's where you use this object that matters. `join` method as well lazy loads the database query by utilising the associated table, but only loading the `Home` table into memory as the associated `User` table is not required. Afterwards you have `merge`, what `merge` method does is a simple way of using a named scope on a joined model. Something like

```
class Home < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :home

  scope :available, ->{ where(available: true) }
end
```

Comment: Then why when I do `users = User.where(status: 3)` it trigger the query?

Comment: I mean when I do that in the console.

Comment: In console everything is executed eagerly, because the console calls inspect on the result of any expression you type so that it can display it to you.  If you want to achieve lazy loading in console just add `false` or `nil` after command `users = User.where(status: 3); false`